# D'Alembert's Principle - rocket

Tags: derivatives

> Consider a one-dimensional, force-free motion of a rocket with constant mass emission $\mu$ and constant outflow velocity **c** of the gases. At $t=0$ let $m=m_0$ and $v=0$.
>
> a) When is the kinetic energy of the rocket at a maximum and what are its mass and velocity at this point in time.
>
> b) Assume a quadratic resistance acts on the movement of the rocket in the form of $R=-\alpha v^2$. In that case the rocket can only achieve a certain velocity $v_c$. Determine $v_c$.
>
> c) Consider a motion of the rocket without resistance in the homogeneous gravitational field of earth. Determine the reached height $h$ as a function of time with the initial value of $m=m_0$ at $t=t_0$.

Here were my ideas so far:

a) First of all the basis. There is a constant mass emission, meaning $\dot{m}=-\mu$.

Now to my approach: The first formula that came to mind was $\sum_i(F_i-m_ia_i-\dot{m_i}v_i)\cdot \partial r_i=0$ Since we only consider a rocket it should be $(F-m_0a_r+\mu v_r)\cdot \partial r=0$, correct?

Now, I'm not sure what force $F$ actually is. Is it the force acting upwards on the rocket or the force acting on the gas particles? Putting that aside: I suppose I should try to find different expressions for $a_r$ and $v_r$? I was thinking that $\mu$ is the mass of the gas "shot" out of the rocket and since their outflow is constant their momentum should be conserved, so something like $p_g=\mu \cdot c=(m_0-\mu t)v_r$? I didn't know how to express the mass of the rocket at some random point, so I was thinking of just going with $m_0-\mu t$. Anyway, This would give me $v_r=\frac{\mu\cdot c}{m_0-\mu t}$.

Giving me $(F-m_0a_r+\mu \frac{\mu\cdot c}{m_0-\mu t})\partial r=0$. Can I assume that $F=\dot{p_g}=0$, because the outflow velocity is constant?

I'm basically lost on b) and c), don't know how to approach them.

Could anyone more fluent in this subject help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of deriving rocket equations, and variable mass equations in general, is to use the impulse-momentum principle -

**The impulse of external forces in time $\delta t=$ the increase in momentum in time $\delta t$**

Conservation of mass implies that ejected particles of mass in time $\delta t$ are assigned a value $-\delta m$

Applying this principle in part a) (assuming $c$ is the ejection speed relative to the rocket) gives:$$(m+\delta m)(v+\delta v)-\delta m(v+\delta v-c)-mv=0$$
$$\Rightarrow m\delta v+c\delta m=0$$

Dividing by $\delta t$ and allowing $\delta t \rightarrow 0$, we have $$m\frac{dv}{dt}=\mu c$$

The kinetic energy is $T=\frac 12 mv^2$

To find the maximum kinetic energy, set $\tfrac{dT}{dt}=0$

From this we get $v=0$ where the kinetic energy is zero, or $v=2c$, which gives the maximum.

To get the mass at this instant solve, with the initial conditions given, the rocket equation in the form (allowing $\delta m\rightarrow0$ instead) $$m\frac{dv}{dm}=-c$$ whereupon $$m=m_0e^{-2}$$

The rest of the question can be solved in the same way...

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I got a quick question, how did you get from $m\frac{dv}{dm}=-c$ to $m=m_0e^{-2}$?

Comment: Separate the variables and integrate to find $m$ when $v=2c$